# Putting synchronous wrapper over asynchronous methods

Tags: c#, events, asynchronous, synchronous

I'm integrating with a PIN device with an api containing asynchronous methods.  For example one of them is called GetStatus and it raises a DeviceStateChangedEvent with the state passed into it as a parameter.

I'd like to have an interface that is not asynchronous over it though, so that when I call GetStatus on my interface it will actually return the status rather than raising an event to pass that data to me.

I'm thinking I could do something like this:

```
public class MSRDevice
{
    StatusInfo _status;
    bool _stateChangedEventCompleted = false;
    IPAD _ipad; // <-- the device

    public MSRDevice()
    {
        //Initialize device, wire up events, etc.
    }

    public StatusInfo GetStatus()
    {
        _ipad.GetStatus() // <- raises StatusChangedEvent
        while(!_stateChangedEventCompleted);
        _stateChangedEventCompleted = false;
        return _status;
    }

    void StateChangedEvent(object sender, DeviceStateChangeEventArgs e) 
    {
         _status = e.StatusInfo;
    }
}
```

Is this a good way to address this or this there a better solution?

Comment: They're async for a reason. Are you sure you can wait?

Comment: Are the `DeviceStateChangedEvent` events synchronized with respect to a call to `GetStatus`?  More clearly, is this a possible sequence of events: `GetStatus`, `GetStatus`, `DeviceStateChangedEvent`, `DeviceStateChangedEvent`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you’re doing in your example is called “[busy-waiting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting)” (or “spinning”), which is unrecommended in most scenarios since it wastes a lot of CPU power. Preferably, you should use a signalling mechanism, such as the `WaitHandle` class, for synchronizing when an event of interest (in your case, `StatusChangedEvent`) has occurred:

```
public class MSRDevice
{
    StatusInfo _status;
    IPAD _ipad; // <-- the device

    private EventWaitHandle waitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);

    public MSRDevice()
    {
        //Initialize device, wire up events, etc.
    }

    public StatusInfo GetStatus()
    {
        _ipad.GetStatus() // <- raises StatusChangedEvent asynchronously
        waitHandle.WaitOne(); // <- waits for signal
        return _status;
    }

    void StateChangedEvent(object sender, DeviceStateChangeEventArgs e) 
    {
        _status = e.StatusInfo;
        waitHandle.Set(); // <- sets signal
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I was pretty sure the while loop was not the way to go but wasn't sure what the right way was.  Thanks for writing out the example!

Answer (score 2):

The best option: code it async.

No; that is a hot loop. It will hammer the CPU. It also isn't guaranteed to exit due to register caching (this is trivial to demonstrate on x86 in particular).

If you need it sync, you should use something like an `AutoResetEvent`.

Comment: Marc, that would be great if I wasn't trying to make an interface that worked for a synchronous device and a non-synchronous device.  There is absolutely no reason we need this device to *ever* act asynchronously so I see it as a benefit to make the interface synchronous and simplify the code.  Thanks for the AutoResetEvent tip, I will check that out.

Comment: FYI, I actually did it the other way around with the interface to the credit card providers.  PC Charge was synchronous and PPI was not, so I made an interface that appeared asynchronous to the consuming code no matter which was used.  In retrospect, that was a mistake because it just made it harder to integrate and maintain for no good reason.

Comment: @BrandonMoore then use either an AutoResetEvent or (if you are familiar with using Pulse/Wait as a signal) `Monitor`.

Comment: Thanks!  I realized my while loop was probably a bad idea to begin with (hence the question).  But if the explanation isn't too long too put in a comment I'm curious why you say it isn't guaranteed to exit due to register caching (or if you have a link to an explanation that would be great too).

Comment: @BrandonMoore: Each processor (or core) has its own cache. If the threads on which `GetStatus` and `StateChangedEvent` are executed run on different processors (or cores), then you run the risk that they would have different copies of the `_stateChangedEventCompleted` field which are never synchronized. In other words, `GetStatus` would always read the field as `false`, even after `StateChangedEvent` sets it to `true`. You can trivially fix this by declaring your variable as `volatile`. Recommended read: [Threading in C#](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx) by Joseph Albahari.

Comment: @BrandonMoore Douglas is entirely right to say that volatile fixes this, but that is a *side-effect* of volatile - not *really* the intended usage. Unless you really really know about instruction re-ordering (and frankly I don't), I would avoid that and use fences instead (`Monitor` and `*ResetEvent` use fences).

Comment: @BrandonMoore: Actually, Marc is correct. Dismiss the `volatile` suggestion in my former comment; it isn’t safe to use in your scenario, since writes and reads may be swapped. A safer approach would be to call `Thread.MemoryBarrier()` to enforce a full memory barrier (full fence). The link I posted goes into all this detail.

Comment: @Douglas Ha, yeah I was just reading that part of the article wondering... and now I see your update.  Apparently you went and read it again too :)  In any case, I just wanted to know that for fun... I definitely have no need to micro-optimize like that.

Comment: @BrandonMoore: Guilty as charged :-) No, such micro-optimizations are typically unnecessary. Sticking to mutual-exclusion locks for critical sections (using the `lock` statement) and signalling mechanisms for thread synchronization (e.g. `AutoResetEvent`) is usually simpler and efficient enough for most purposes.

Comment: @Douglas I wonder if this might be a problem I was having months ago.  There is a particularly poorly written form in our project that uses a Timer control.  When a certain action is completed it fills in some text boxes and after some changes I made to the form it started sporadically deciding not to fill in one of the text boxes.  The field the box got its value from was always populated at the end of the Timer procedure, but after exiting it sometimes would not be.

Comment: That would be hard to tell without seeing the code. Maybe you could extract the relevant parts and post it as a question? (That said, unexpected results in threaded code are usually caused by race conditions within your flow logic, rather than cache inconsistencies.)